# "Post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with no output" - Meaning of this? How to fix?

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven, subclipse

I've done some research on this error, but haven't found anything helpful yet. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and am attempting to commit to a repo through Subclipse. The error just started popping up randomly, as I had done many commits in a row without issue up to it. I can't think of anything that has changed.

Most importantly, I'm wondering what effect this error has on me. As in: is my work getting committed successfully even with the error? If my work is being committed, what is the problem? And of course, I would like to know what the resolution is, if there is one. Thanks.

Comment: Please give the full output of the error without that it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: That's all it gives me, in a little error box popup

Comment: But in the error box you will find a message.

Comment: @khmarbaise: that message (the title of the question) _is_ the message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is my work getting committed successfully even with the error?

Yes. You have troubles with **post**-commit hook, which fired after adding transaction as new revision into repository

> If my work is being committed, what is the problem?

Problem is post-commit hook, which exit with code 1 == Error (for some reason) instead of 0 == OK

> I would like to know what the resolution is, if there is one.

Find used hook, read source, define why `exit 1` was used for (some?) commits. Maybe disable hook at all

Comment: Issue seemed to resolve itself after a day, maybe something was screwed up on our repo server. Thanks for the concise explanation, though.